# Adding Rows Based on the Number of Months Between two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set which contains the the monthly budget for types of services a client can receive.  The **SERVICES_ID** is the type of service, the **Begin_DT** and **End_DT**  give the range of time the service is good for, the  **COST_PER_MONTH**  gives the amount budgeted monthly, and  **NUMBER_OF_MONTHS** gives the number of months that the budget for that service is good for.

Here is a sample data set, you will notice there are two clients each have two services budgeted. One client has both services for 12 months, the other has one service 12 months and another for 6.

```
CREATE TABLE Services (
    ID int,
    SERVICES_ID int,
    Begin_DT datetime, 
    End_DT datetime, 
    COST_PER_MONTH  int, 
    NUMBER_OF_MONTHS int)

('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012' 203.2,  12)
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012' 78.2,   12)
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012', 469.2,  6)
('13862',   10,  '6/3/2011',    '6/3/2012',  78.2,  12)
```

I need to have query which adds in a **Month** and a **Year** variable and adds rows for each month the service is budgeted in the month range between **Begin_DT**  and  **End_DT**. This is what I am looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE Services_monthly (
    ID int,
    SERVICES_ID int,
    Begin_DT datetime, 
    End_DT datetime, 
    Month int,
    Year int,
    COST_PER_MONTH  int, 
    NUMBER_OF_MONTHS int)

('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    7,  2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    8,  2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    9,  2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    10, 2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    11, 2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    12, 2011,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    1,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    2,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    3,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    4,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    6,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   9,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    7,  2012,   203.2,  12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    7,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    8,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    9,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    10, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    11, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    12, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    1,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    2,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    3,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    4,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    6,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('10178',   10, '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    7,  2012,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     12, 2011,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     1,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     2,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     3,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     4,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     5,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   12, '12/8/2011',    '6/3/2012',     6,  2012,   469.2,  6),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     6,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     7,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     8,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     9,  2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     10, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     11, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',     12, 2011,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',      1, 2012,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',      2, 2012,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',      3, 2012,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',      4, 2012,   78.2,   12),
('13862',   10, '6/3/2011',     '6/3/2012',      5, 2012,   78.2,   12)
```

Comment: Create a calendar table.  A table with the full calendar from (for example) 1st Jan 1900 to 31st Dec 2070, including meta-data and indexes that let you quickly and easily identify which dates are the start of the week, month, year, etc, and lets you record which dates are bank-holidays, etc, etc. Then join on it.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks. That would be a great solution but I don't have the permissions to create tables a my job. Do you think there may be another way?

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/901ca/16)**

```
SELECT  ID, 
        SERVICES_ID,
        Begin_DT, 
        End_DT,
        MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,n.number, Begin_DT)) AS Month,
        YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,n.number, Begin_DT)) AS Year,
        COST_PER_MONTH , 
        NUMBER_OF_MONTHS
FROM   Services  s,
(SELECT DISTINCT number 
 FROM master..spt_values 
 WHERE number >= 0 
 AND number < 100)  n
WHERE  n.number <= s.NUMBER_OF_MONTHS
```

Your result wrong, you need to add last row to your data :

```
| 13862 |          10 |     June, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 | June, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     6 | 2012 |           78.2 |               12 |
```

I think my fiddle works like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with number_cte (number) as
(select distinct number from master..spt_values where number between 1 and 1000) 

Select  ID, SERVICES_ID,Begin_DT, End_DT,COST_PER_MONTH , NUMBER_OF_MONTHS
from   Services_monthly  s cross join number_cte n
where  n.number <= s.NUMBER_OF_MONTHS
```

Also, the best solution would be to create a table variable and populate it with numbers.

Comment: would it be possible to create a Month and Year variable using the query above?